# looping through command to submit several jobs

Tags: linux, bash, for

I am submitting a job to a computer.

It looks something like this:

```
    mpirun -np 12 example_S57 -o S57.results -r S57.final
    mpirun -np 12 example_S58 -o S58.results -r S58.final
 ...
 ...
 ...
    mpirun -np 12 example_S74 -o S74.results -r S74.final
```

How can I loop through this command and run this for S57 up to S74 within my script without having to type out each command?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
for example in S{57..74}; do
    mpirun -np 12 "example_$example" -o "$example.results" -r "$example.final"
done
```

This uses a brace expansion in `bash` to create the `Snn` values to loop over.  The value `$example` will in each iteration be one of these values and can be used when calling the `mpirun` command.

Comment: @JacksonHart (You posted a comment here that you deleted with an error message in it. This error seems unrelated to anything that you show in the question).

Comment: Yeah I made a mistake. Your solution works, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Using GNU Parallel it looks like this:

```
parallel mpirun -np 12 example_{} -o {}.results -r {}.final ::: S{57..74}
```